# How to diplay MATLAB output in readable format?

Tags: matlab, formatting

I am using MATLAB for symbolic calculations.
It always give output of mathematical expressions in one line which is not very readable
for example-

```
  >> syms x y z  
  >> int(sin(y*cos(x)),y)  
  >> ans =   
  -cos(y*cos(x))/cos(x)
```

Is there any way to get a readable output like how I read in text books.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pretty`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/pretty.html):

```
syms x y z  
s = int(sin(y*cos(x)),y);
pretty(s)
```